# What is the FQDN to use when adding Puppet extension to Azure Windows VM

Tags: azure, puppet, azure-virtual-machine

I created a Windows Server VM on Azure. After the VM has successfully been created, I want to add Puppet extension to it. I selected the VM, then I clicked on extensions and clicked add then I selected Puppet and then I clicked create. There was only one field that I had to fill which is "Puppet Master Server". This is supposed to be the FQDN of the Puppet master server that will manage this code.

It seems that I'm missing a step. Maybe I'm supposed to create a Puppet Master server. I had tried to created one, and it was successfully created, but alongside it also created many other things that I don't need like a Linux VM, VNet, ...etc.

I'm confused about this. Any explanation is highly appreciated.

PS: I'm using the new Azure portal

Comment: Is this going to be masterless provisioning with Puppet?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. I'm just wondering: is the step of creating a puppet master server mandatory before adding the puppet extension? If so, is there a way to create the puppet master server without creating the other things along with it?